# HTTP Methods blocking does not work on subdomain

Tags: apache-2.4

I performed the blocking of methods other than GET, POST and OPTIONS in apache.conf, and when I try to run the server via IP the blocking works.

But when configuring the same blocking on a subdomain (via sites-available), this blocking does not occur.
What could I have done wrong?

> apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
        Require all denied
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

> sites-available/subdomain.example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain.example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well\-known/acme\-challenge/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile      /certs/example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /certs/example.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /certs/example-intermediary.crt

    Protocols h2 http/1.1

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"

    Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"

    <Directory /var/www/html/subdomain.example.com>
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted

        <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
            Require all denied
        </LimitExcept>
    </Directory>

    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain.example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This lock is not working because when executing a request with PUT, DELETE, LOCK, etc, the page content is returned normally.

Comment: The "AllowOverride None" on /var/www perhaps?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I put this setting, because of the CIS recommendation (4.4). >"Ensure OverRide Is Disabled for All Directories" - "Search the Apache configuration files (httpd.conf and any included configuration files) to find AllowOverride directives.
Set the value for all AllowOverride directives to None. "

Comment: I'm barking up the wrong tree, allowoverride only manages .htaccess directives. The page content isn't coming from any cache?

Comment: There is no cache. In Apache's own log it shows the request made with the other methods.

Comment: No symbolic links under /var/www ? Use separate logs for this virtualhost. Try "require valid-user" to see if you hit the limitexcept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stop using that complicated old way to restrict methods.

Load mod_allowmehtods.so and define what you want to allow instead in a more simple fashion.

```
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
    
<Directory /var/www> 
#other directives
AllowMethods GET POST OPTIONS 
</Directory>
```

Unless you override this in a subdirectory with something else, this will work serverwide. Try and let us know.

Comment: Strange that the documentation (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html) doesn't mention the depreciation.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille True, I certainly went ahead of myself, certainly worth a debate in the ASF, mod_allowmethods is much simpler and helps stop using Limit LimitExcept which can cause confusion. Allow me to correct my comment, thanks for pointing it out!